# du, df showing inconsistent hard drive usage

Tags: disk-usage, disk-management, df, du

Ubuntu 20.04
1T built-in drive
5T Seagate Basic external USB drive

Yesterday I moved a very large postgres database to an external USB drive, and then deleted the database directory from the main hard drive. Since then, the df command says my 1T built-in drive has only 31G of free space left. The du command contradicts this.

**Edit**: When I moved the database, I actually shut it down, backed it up and upgraded the version of postgres. Then I created a new database on the USB drive and restored the backup to it. Toward the end of that, the system gave me a warning about low disk space but the new database appears to have all the data in it.

Here is what I see when I run `du`, excluding the external USB drive. It shows that 322G of space is being used, which is pretty close to what I would expect.

```
$ sudo du -sh --exclude=/media /
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/proc/4833/task/4833/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/4833/task/4833/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/4833/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/4833/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
322G    /
```

However, when I run `df`, the main partition on that drive shows that 839G are in use and only 31G are free. I don't believe this is correct. I tried unplugging the external USB drive, but it made no difference. I also tried rebooting the system, but that made no difference either.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2  916G  839G   31G  97% /
```

I also ran `lsof | grep '(deleted)'` and it returns a lot of files, some of which seem to be listed more than once, but I don't know how to permanently remove them.

The files shown by the lsof command mostly are associated with the Brave browser. I don't see any that look like postgres files. Although, I get the following warning:

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this without locking up the system so bad I need to reformat the drive?

Comment: Check that your mount point directories are really empty.  After a mount, the files are not seen, but of course, they still take up room.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you never restarted the process (which may be the PostgreSQL server), and even less so the entire machine.

Please note that there is a difference between

- moving a file within the same filesystem, as this only moves a directory link.
- moving a file across filesystems or physical disks, as this involves copying and deleting.

If a file is deleted, then actually only its directory entry (a link to the file data) is removed. The correct term is *unlinked*, as the function in libc is called `unlink`, because this is what really happens.

If there is still a process which has the file opened (a file handle pointing to that file), this process still claims the disk space occupied by the file. As long as this is the case, the disk space is not yet freed, and hence `df` shows a value as if the file is still present, while `du` does not see the file anymore because the file is really no longer listed in the directory.

As soon as all processes close the file, also `df` will show the disk space as freed.

As a bottom line - how to remove these files entirely? Make sure that the process which has them opended closes them (be it by ending the process).

Comment: I backed up, shutdown, uninstalled, upgraded the database but opted to leave the data directory and deleted it later. Then I created a new database on the other drive and restored it to there with the new version. The files shown by lsof don't seem related to postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Something to take into account: make sure the Trash for root and user are empty.

From top to bottom all the different elements related to du, df, and locks of files, and how to clear them to have df report more free space. I would assume a reboot should do this too though so I am a bit puzzled. If this is not a fix for your problem comment this answer and I will remove it (or adjust it)

Why `du` and `df` show different results:

> - `du` is used to estimate file space usage—space used under a particular directory or files on a file system.
> - `df` is used to display the amount of available disk space for file systems on which the invoking user has appropriate read access.
>
> After deleting a file, the disk space occupied by this file will be slowly released. The result of the command `du` doesn't include the size of the deleting file but the result of the command `df` includes the size of the deleting file due to its disk space is not released immediately.
>
> So after deleting the file, the results of `df` and `du` are different until the disk space is released.

As you already know you can get a list of deleted files which are still held open by applications (I added COMMAND so you can search for that more easily)(add a  `| grep postgres` to this to filter on postgres):

```
lsof | egrep "deleted|COMMAND"
```

Some examples:

```
COMMAND     PID   TID TASKCMD              FD      TYPE             DEVI
CE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
pipewire  35916                         24u      REG                0
,1      2312       7234 /memfd:pipewire-memfd (deleted)
pipewire  35916                         27u      REG                0
,1      2312       7235 /memfd:pipewire-memfd (deleted)
pipewire  35916                         30u      REG                0
,1      2312         67 /memfd:pipewire-memfd (deleted)
pipewire  35916 35944 pipewire          24u      REG                0
,1      2312       7234 /memfd:pipewire-memfd (deleted)
pipewire  35916 35944 pipewire          27u      REG
```

(those are chrome temp files)

If in your case there is a file there pointing to postgres note the PID and do a (35916 as an example):

```
  ls -l /proc/35916/fd | grep deleted
```

Example:

```
lrwx------ 1 rinzwind rinzwind 64 apr 30 20:41 24 -> /memfd:pipewire-memfd (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 rinzwind rinzwind 64 apr 30 20:41 27 -> /memfd:pipewire-memfd (deleted)
lrwx------ 1 rinzwind rinzwind 64 apr 30 20:41 30 -> /memfd:pipewire-memfd (deleted)
```

If you see your large files you can do a (again: change the numbers to what is shown for you):

```
> /proc/35916/fd/30
```

and in this case the data in memory linked to "30" will free up (64kb here) resulting in `du` and `df` matching their numbers more accurately.

Be very careful with this as this might crash any service that is actually using the file.

Comment: The COMMAND column shows only these commands: pulseaudi, Xorg, gnome-she, gnome-ter and brave. If I shut down the Brave browser, the brave files are gone from the list. When I start it again, they come back. Rebooting the system does not fix the problem.